# center div when xs, align to right otherwise

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 buttons:

```
<div class="row pt-20">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6  text-right pr-20">
            <a href="{!! URL::action('TournamentController@create') !!}" type="button"
               class="btn border-primary btn-flat text-primary disabled text-uppercase p-10 ">{{ trans('core.see_open_tournaments') }}
                {{--( {{trans('core.soon')}} )--}}
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 text-left pl-20">
            <a href="{!! URL::action('TournamentController@create') !!}" type="button"
               class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase p-10">{{ trans('core.create_new_tournament') }}
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

What I would like to achieve is align right/left when resolution > xs, and align center when res = xs.

What is the best way to achieve it???

I was thinking remove text-right in div, and use media queries to do it in css, but I think there is more elegant way to do it, isn't it????

Tx!

Comment: Just use an `@media` query. What screen widths do you want it applied to?

Comment: xs to center, and all other res left and right. https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: What's xs? Please be more specific

Comment: it's a bootstrap resolution : https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: Well set your media query to use whatever xs represents.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class called `text-center-xs` and add the appropriate styles to your custom stylesheet:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .text-center-xs {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```